# Image not uploading Flutter

Tags: flutter

So i am trying to make a page where you can upload a photo. I am following this tutorial:
https://amazevlley.blogspot.com/2019/02/image-picker-in-flutter-flutter.html

everything is going perfect, it gives no errors but the ting is that once i try to upload a photo, nothing happens and in the console i get this:

```
D/MediaScannerConnection( 5702): Scanned /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.beatact.android/files/Pictures/8ba23cd4-364b-464e-b8a6-f0314ae1b1c21240136766163793817.jpg to null
```

so it sends null in so nothing appears? How ca i solve issue?

```
File _image;
Future getImageFromCam() async { // for camera    
  var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  setState(() {
    _image = image;
  });
}
Future getImageFromGallery() async { // for gallery    
  var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  setState(() {
    _image = image;
  });
}
```

.

```
   ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: < Widget > [
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height: 200.0, child: Center(
            child: _image == null ? Text('No image selected.') :
            Image.file(_image), ), ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: < Widget > [
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: getImageFromCam, tooltip: 'Pick Image', child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo), ), FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: getImageFromGallery, tooltip: 'Pick Image', child: Icon(Icons.wallpaper), ),
          ], ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: Please add the code for the upload function, it is not clear what might be the problem, could be the path, could be anything else.

Comment: I have edited it!

Comment: Are you sure the app has "external storage" permissions? Also, according to the plugin's docs https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker there are some entries in the Android Manifest file for API version less than 29, maybe encountering issues there

Comment: How can i enable external storage?

Comment: You will need to add "<uses-permission>" tags to your AndroidManifest.xml document. Here it is from the github repo of the code from the video in your linked tutorial: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/image_picker/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: i put both of them but it still doesn't work..

Comment: I would say try to implement the example project in the plugin's github: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/image_picker/image_picker They have a specific instruction for Android API < 29 which might be what's causing your issue

Comment: i added in the androidmanifest.xml exactly waht it writes there for androind api over 29 and it still doesnt work..